# Emailing new team members about conference of interest

Tags: professionalism, email, off-site-events

I've recently moved in to a new company/team, and I was thinking of sending an email to the rest of the team members with the team leaders in CC to bring to their attention a computer science conference (not strictly related to work but we all work as full stack developers, so it's relevant enough for anyone willing to see something more and or new).

The conference is in August and call for participation for it went up yesterday.

Is it appropriate to forward the call for participation email to the rest of the team (with manager/consultant CC'd as well) or is it inappropriate?

If it helps you answer, I do think it's interesting material (with the actual schedule pending, of course) and I do intend to participate personally,so its not like I bring it up pointlessly, especially since this year's edition will be in our city.

**EDIT :** More info, current workload is more than manageable, conference is on a weekend and admission for it is free.

Comment: 'Participate personally' - as in you are paying for yourself?

Comment: Its free to participate, I just wanted to mention by this that  i'm  not only mailing them just cause  but because I personally believe its interesting.

Comment: I don't see any reason to ask your manager first. Sounds like a good way to get to know your new team out of work hours.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yeah, not planning to mail 250 people about this :D

Comment: @ayrtonclark Thought so myself, plus it can show my managers some of my eagerness to learn things and multi-dimensional progress which is true as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd discuss this with your manager first. Maybe he/she knows that some tight deadlines are coming up, and attending a conference (especially with the *whole team*) might not fit into the schedule. If you make the team too enthusiastic upfront, by forwarding the call for participation, it might be an awkward situation for the manager having to disappoint them.

It also gives him/her the opportunity to propose an alternative, like sending one or two people and have them hold a presentation about the highlights to their colleagues. Or maybe even promise to sponsor the fees or having the event count as working time if your team meets certain goals by the end of July.

In case the conference is outside working hours, it'd be no problem if you email it right away. It's work-related, after all. Still, this might be a chance to improve your manager's view of you, by consulting with him/her first.

Comment: I do agree with what you mentioned, if it was on work days and/or we had tight schedule, and I ll certainly keep those in mind if such a situation arise.. 
To give some more hindsight, at current stage we re only doing maintenance/refactoring/bug-solving and the conference is luckily on the weekend so those shouldnt be issues.Mainly asking if its proper etiquette to mail the team(and team managers) about something that isnt entirely work related but isnt entirely unrelated and might be of their interest like this one.